# C# userform in excel pending while user method running

Tags: c#, excel

I am a newbie to excel programing, I now have a problem with my excel add-ins code. My add-ins call out a Mainform. Whenever I  call my method from this form's button to do some tasks, such as searching huge data, the Mainform is frozen, it's inevitable. But when the method is running, assume it then will call a childform, this child form is also pending, I cannot do anything with it.

My purpose is to call a child form to add in a progress bar and an Abort button to cancel the running method.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance for your help.
vuhi

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to multi-thread to allow that; multi-threading using **just** VBA cannot be done.

See the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5721588/2258) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5721564/2258) for more details.