# Is scripting.dictionary multithreaded?

Tags: multithreading, excel, vba

I am trying to use Scripting.Dictionary in Excel VBA and was just wondering if anyone knows if it is single or multi threaded?

Thanks

Comment: VBA is a single-threaded environment. What are you asking?

Comment: But that doesn't mean that Scripting.Dictionary is, which is what OP is asking.

Comment: multitheading can mean many things so a better explanation of what he wants to know may get him an answer. I dont understand his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to worry about the threading model of `Scripting.Dictionary` in VBA, as VBA runs in a single threaded apartment.

See [Multi-threading in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721564/multi-threading-in-vba)