# OleDbConnection close method taking long execution time

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection

```
        conStr = String.Format(conStr, FilePath, isHDR);
        OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conStr);
        OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

        //Get the name of First Sheet
        connExcel.Open();
        DataTable dtExcelSchema;
        dtExcelSchema =            connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        connExcel.Close();
```

I am using above code to read excel. But it stuck at  connExcel.Close(); for few seconds and then move to next statement. This is causing late processing on the page. Any suggestions??

Updating my question to give more details.

test case:-
I uploaded an xls file it took normal time.
I uploaded an xlsx file it halt at connExcel.close() for 25sec.
Now i uploaded an xls file and it halt for xls also.

i have used following connection strings

for xls :-
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};
                         Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"

for xlsx :-
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};
                         Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721564/multi-threading-in-vba

Comment: Try the solution in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27245931/736172

Comment: Hi Ahmad, it is a c# code that simply reads emailids in excel. It doesnt require multithreading. it simply stuck at connExcel.Close(); for 20-40 seconds then gives output.

Comment: I run the same code on server and its working fine. but on local machine it is causing issue. I am using visual studio express edition.

Comment: @Chandikumar Hi Chandik did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;     @Bassie I included these three things. and used only one connection string for both xls and xlsx.     connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=No;IMEX=-1\"";

Comment: @Chandikumar Ah, thanks for your response, but I am seeing this error when using `ACE.OLEDB` to connect to MS Acccess .. Do you have any idea if Access actually supports extended properties? Can't find any examples