# How to run multiple functions at same time begining from another one in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have workbook made to create 3 excel instances and run the program in each one. I make it to improve the performance using multiple cores. I'm trying to run it without struggle in a different scope.

Example of code

```
Sub Initiate()
Dim spath2 As String
Dim spath3 As String
Dim xlApp As Application
Dim xlFFQ1 As Application
Dim xlFFQ2 As Application
Dim xlFFQ3 As Application


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

spath1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\program1.xlsm"
spath2 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\program2.xlsm"
spath3 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\program3.xlsm"

Set xlApp1 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlApp2 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlApp3 = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

xlApp1.Workbooks.Open (spath1)
xlApp2.Workbooks.Open (spath2)
xlApp3.Workbooks.Open (spath3)


'those lines are independents and want to run each one without waiting the end of another. xlApp1/xlApp2/xlApp3 are different excel instances
xlApp1.Run "doMyStuffs"
xlApp2.Run "doMyStuffs"
xlApp3.Run "doMyStuffs"
```

If something isn't quite clear, just say that I make it better written.

Comment: You want multi-threading, which, unfortunately, isn't possible in VBA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multi-threading in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721564/multi-threading-in-vba)

Comment: each workbook opens in a different instance, I just need to make a "RUN" in each one without using the manual mode (open each workbook and execute its macro).

Comment: Yes, I understand. And I'm telling you you can't do that in VBA.

Comment: If you're desperate: [Excel Hero blog post](http://www.excelhero.com/blog/2010/05/multi-threaded-vba.html)

Comment: If you're really desperate, consider using VB.NET instead. The syntax is mostly similar to VBA with some differences that you will need to learn. It will allow you to use multi-threading to accomplish tasks though.

Comment: Threading can be mimicked in VBA using some of the ideas in this link http://analystcave.com/excel-multithreading-vba-with-vba-worker-threads/, better to write in .net though, your Excel can call this also.

Comment: Thanks for all help. @Nathan_Sav guess this link will help me! First I will read it and apply and later I come back with the solution.

Comment: And I ain't desperate D:

Answer (score 0):

I used the Task Scheduler as starter of my instances. More info [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/):