# how i can do data entry to multiple webpages by getting information from excel

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, tabs

```
Sub accessExistingIEtabs()

     boolWindowFound = False
     Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
     WinCount = objShell.Windows.Count
     winNo = 0
        Set IE = objShell.Windows(winNo)
         boolWindowFound = True
         If boolWindowFound Then
         Set doc = IE.document
         End If
                doc.getElementsByClassName("a-input-text a-form-normal ui-autocomplete-nested-button ui- 
                autocomplete-input")(0).Value = "italy"

end sub
```

'this  code work just on tab number 0 I WANT TO USE  EDIT  TO IT  SO I CAN CONTROL MULTIPLE PAGES  LIKE'  'TAB 1 AND  TAB 2 AND  MORE  TO DO DATA  ENTRY TO MULTIPLE PAGES BY GETTING  INFORMATION FROM EXCEL BUT' '
'AT SAME TIME  NOT TAB BY TAB' ?
end sub

Comment: Please don't SHOUT here- we can all hear you in regular case.

Comment: sorry i don't understand  you english isn't my language

Comment: What do you mean by `tab` without seeing the site, its hard to advise, you may have to adjust the `(0)` after getting the elements.  Or loop through your windows `objShell.Windows(winNo)` incrementing winNo and looking at what it contains.

Comment: You know, if you set *boolWindowFound = True* and asking in the next line for *boolWindowFound = True* that always matches? Only to talk about one problem in your code. Whats about *WinCount = objShell.Windows.Count*? Only to talk about another part of your "code". Sorry, but almost everything in your code is wrong and I think nobody realy knows what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You said,

> this code work just on tab number 0 I WANT TO USE EDIT TO IT SO I CAN
>   CONTROL MULTIPLE PAGES LIKE' 'TAB 1 AND TAB 2 AND MORE TO DO DATA
>   ENTRY TO MULTIPLE PAGES BY GETTING INFORMATION FROM EXCEL BUT' ' '**AT
>   SAME TIME NOT TAB BY TAB**

To execute some code simultaneously, the user needs to create multiple threads.

For your information, multithreading is not supported in VBA. VBA can work on single thread at a time. So it is not possible to fulfill your requirement with VBA code to do the data entry in multiple pages at the same time.

You can do the data entry tab by tab.

If you still need to work with VBA then you can refer links below may give you some workaround ideas.

1. [Multi-threading in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721564/multi-threading-in-vba)
2. [Excel/VBA : Multi-threading example](http://mikejuniperhill.blogspot.com/2017/06/excelvba-multi-threading-example.html)
3. [EXCEL VBA MULTITHREADING](http://www.audeser.com/excel-vba-multithreading/)