# Run Userform simultaneously with other function

Tags: vba

I want to run the userform with simultaneously running other function so that i dont have to wait more.

```
UserForm1.Show

'Dim remainder As Long
'Dim i As Long, j As Long
'remainder = 0
'For i = 1 To 200
'UserForm1.Label4.Width = UserForm1.Label4.Width + 1
'''If i Mod 2 = 0 Then
'''remainder = remainder + 1
'''End If
'For j = 1 To 600
'DoEvents
'Next j
'Next i
'Unload UserForm1
'
'MsgBox "Loading is Complete"




'MsgBox "Please Wait ! File are Being Loaded"

Instancecode = GetInstanceCode(Market_Name)
        ' To copy Distributor data file
            Distributor_data_filepath = GetDistributorData_Filepath(Instancecode)
            Distributor_data_FileName = GetDistributorData_Filename(Instancecode)
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Distributor_data_filepath
            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Copy After:=Workbooks("FORM_V79_17082020").Sheets(Workbooks("FORM_V79_17082020").Worksheets.count)
        
            
            Workbooks(Distributor_data_FileName).Close
            
          ActiveSheet.Protect "Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
          ActiveSheet.Protect AllowFiltering:=True
```

I want to run the user form along with the next function instance code.

Comment: VBA is _single-threaded_, thus can only "do one thing at any time".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-threading in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721564/multi-threading-in-vba)

Comment: Show the form non-modal: `UserForm1.Show vbModeless`