# Animated GIF runs, but only after script finishes

Tags: excel, vba, animation, gif

I have created a GIF that is supposed to run when I run a search script, however it only runs at the end of the script (it is just a picture of the GIF until the script finishes). Is there a way to make it run the whole time? I have tried making the GIF a separate UserForm, but it still freezes while the script is running. I have tried toggling the different toggles on and off (Automatic Calculations, Enable Events, Screen Updating) and I have tried changing the placement of the "Do Events", but I cannot get the GIF to start animating.

```
Public Sub SearchButton_Click()

WebBrowser1.Visible = True
WebBrowser1.Navigate "C:\Users\E100676\Pictures\loading.gif"
DoEvents
WebBrowser1.Document.body.Scroll = "no"

On Error Resume Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.EnableEvents = False
DoEvents



Dim found As Range, totalcells As Long, B(), nr As Long, nc As Integer, i As Long, j As Integer
Dim Counter As Long, CurrentProgress As Double, ProgressPercentage As Double, BarWidth As Long
nr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(3, 2), Cells(3, 2).End(xlDown))) + 2
nc = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(2, 2).End(xlToRight))) + 1
ReDim B(3 To nr, 2 To nc)

'create array
For i = 3 To nr
    For j = 2 To nc
        B(i, j) = Cells(i, j)
    Next
Next

'search
Counter = 0
If TextBox1 <> "" Then
    For i = 3 To nr
        For j = 2 To nc
            On Error Resume Next
            If InStr(1, B(i, j), CBK200UserForm.TextBox1, vbTextCompare) Then
                If IsError(InStr(1, B(i, j), CBK200UserForm.TextBox1, vbTextCompare)) Then
                    Exit For
                End If
                    Cells(i, 1).Resize(1, nc).Interior.Color = RGB(200, 255, 200)
                    Counter = Counter + 1
ESkip:
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If Counter = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No search results found.", vbExclamation, "Search Error"
        GoTo Skipfilter
    End If
    If CBK200UserForm.Combo1.ListIndex = -1 Then
        Cells(2, 2).AutoFilter field:=2
    End If
Else
    MsgBox "The search box is empty.", vbInformation, "Search Error"

    GoTo Skipfilter
End If

Cells(2, 2).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=RGB(200, 255, 200), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
Skipfilter:

WebBrowser1.Visible = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5721564/multi-threading-in-vba

Comment: In short, VBA does not multithread, so it would be very complicated to get it to work. It's not like a setting you are missing or something, it's just not designed to do what you want. There are alternatives like using the Status Bar as a progress bar. Lots of examples of that on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I will give that a try thanks.

Answer (score 0):

very interesting idea and I like it.
To display an animated GIF while running a script in VBA, you can set the UserForm as modeless by changing the ShowModal property to False in the UserForm properties. Below is an example code :

```
'In UserForm1
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    WebBrowser1.Visible = True
    WebBrowser1.Navigate "Path to your animate.gif"
    DoEvents
    WebBrowser1.Document.body.Scroll = "no"
End Sub

'In some Module
Sub DisplayAnimatedGIF()
    ' Show the UserForm as modeless
    UserForm1.Show vbModeless
    
    ' Run your script or code here
    For i = 1 To 2000
        ' Your code logic goes here, for an example, just counting number
        ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = i
        DoEvents
    Next i
    
    ' Close the UserForm when the script is done
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

It displays UserForm1 as modeless using the vbModeless parameter with the Show method. This allows the UserForm to be displayed without blocking the execution of your script.

Your script or code logic runs within the loop. In this example, it counts to 2000, but you can replace this with your actual script.
After your script is finished, unloads the UserForm.